# How do I add a ProgressDialog to this

Tags: java, android, progressdialog

I am populating a `RecyclerView` from `Parse.com` and as its on the same thread, I am looking to add a `ProgressDialog` until the data is completely loaded in. But, confused, how do I do it.

Here is the code so far:

```
    public class BigBoard extends ActionBarActivity {

    private List<Person> persons;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    RVAdapter adapter;
    String a,b;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Parse.initialize(this, "app-id", "client-key");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_big_board);
        initializeData(); // <----- This is where initialization begins
        adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);


        rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);


        initializeAdapter();

    }

    private void initializeData(){
        persons = new ArrayList<>();


        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Credentials");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> credentialList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for(int i=0;i<credentialList.size();i++)
                    {
                        a=credentialList.get(i).getString("Name");
                        b=credentialList.get(i).getString("SurName");
                        persons.add(new Person(a,b));



                        Log.d("OUT", "So the Val::------> " +a +b);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
        //persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old"));
        //persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old"));
        //persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old"));

    }

    private void initializeAdapter(){

        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }




}
```

So I am loading data to the list from the method `initializeData()`, And is it possible to run a `ProgressDialog` till this is completed? or should I go for an `AsyncTask()` to implement it? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Basically for a progress dialog you can start it when you want it to and you can dismiss it when the job is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing right now is not correct, because you are actually parsing n/w data on the UI thread. Even if you show the `ProgressDialog`, it would be a bad user experience, because the `ProgressDialog` animation would not be smooth, since your UI thread is constantly busy in the `initializeData()` method

You should use your `initializeData()` method in `AsyncTask` only. In the meantime, show `ProgressDialog` from the `onCreate()` method. When your `initializeData()` method completes, dismiss the `ProgressDialog`